# Is there any difference between element.addEventListener('load', func) and element.onload=func?

Tags: javascript, html

Is there any difference between `element.addEventListener('load', func)` and `element.onload=func`?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The DOM "load" event still does only work very limited. That means it'll only fire for the `window` object, images and `<script>` elements for instance. The same goes for the direct `onload` assignment. There is no technical difference between those two. Probably `.onload =` has a better cross-browser availability.

However, you cannot assign a load event to a `<div>` or `<span>` element or whatnot.